# C#_Regex_.Oftype<match>()

Tags: c#, regex

Pls explain me this code .Oftype(). I've searched GG for 2 weeks but there is a little result. So, i can't understand totally.
My code:

```
String source = "Car2Bike6Ship6Bike3Car64Ship56"
var result = Regex
.Matches(source, "(?<name>[A-Z_[ạảàáãăắẳằặẵâấẩầậẫóỏòọõôốổồộỗơớởờợỡéèẻẹẽêếềểệễúùủụũưứừửựữíìỉịĩýỳỷỵỹđ_ẠẢÀÁÃĂẮẲẰẶẴÂẤẨẦẬẪÓỎÒỌÕÔỐỔỒỘỖƠỚỞỜỢỠÉÈẺẸẼÊẾỀỂỆỄÚÙỦỤŨƯỨỪỬỰỮÍÌỈỊĨÝỲỶỴỸĐ_a-z]+)(?<size>[0-9]+)")
.OfType<Match>()
.Select(match => new
{
    name = match.Groups["name"].Value,
    size = int.Parse(match.Groups["size"].Value),
})

.GroupBy(value => value.name)
.Select(chunk => String.Format("{0}: {1}",
   chunk.Key, String.Join(" + ", chunk.Select(item => item.size))));
        String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);

        report = report.Replace(": 0", ":");
        report = report.Replace(": +", ":");
        Console.Write(report);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`OfType<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) is an extension method of non-generic `IEnumerable`, which makes it into an `IEnumerable<T>`. The reason it is used in your code sample is to let you call `match.Groups` inside `Select`.

Since `Matches` method returns [`MatchCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection(v=vs.110).aspx), which implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<Match>` LINQ expressions need to use either a `Cast<T>` or `OfType<T>` to let LINQ statements that follow utilize type information from the actual type of the collection being enumerated.